# I can not find my php.ini file

Tags: php

While learning to set up php to be able to send mail I came across the need to edit the php.ini file. The problem is that when I go to `<localhost>/~username/phpinfo.php` it tells me it is located at `/Library/Server/Web/Config/php` however the `Web` directory does not exist on my server. So where is my php.ini file? I have looked at answers to the same question by others and still was not able to find it. If I need to create it, how do I go about doing that?

I am using a macbook pro as my server running Yosemite.

Thanks in advance!

UPDATE:

So it looks like I found my php.ini file but it is not where php says it is looking phpinfo.php says its looking in /Library/Server/Web/Config/php should I copy the file to this location? also my file is actually named php.ini.default, does this need to be named as just php.ini?

Comment: Create a temporary php file with `<?php phpinfo();` in it. Access the file from your browser and it will show you the ini file its loading.

Comment: @NicolásCarlo, That is the phpinfo.php page that I mentioned

Comment: Try opening a console and running the command: `whereis php.ini`. It should tell you at which location(s) the file is present. Usually it's in `/etc/php.ini`, but it can differ per installation.

Comment: @Oldskool there is no output from that command

Comment: There are php.ini.default-* files, are these what I am looking for?

Comment: http://serverfault.com/questions/209252/find-or-enable-php-ini-on-ubuntu-10-10

Comment: check here - /etc/php5/cli/php.ini

Answer (score 2, accepted):

execute this command

```
locate php.ini
```

This will give you a list of all files with names where 'php.ini' is a part of it.

E.g.

```
/etc/php.ini
/etc/php.ini.rpmnew
/home/myuser/mywebsite.com/demo/local_php.ini
```

...

Comment: this confirms the php.ini files that I have found, see my update

Comment: This is bad behaviour to update your question after an answer has been given to it. You did completely change your question.

Comment: I have not confirmed that this is the correct file due to the fact that there are several with similar names, none of which are just php.ini. If you could confirm that this is the file I am looking for then I will accept the answer. but at this point my original question has not been solved because it is still possible that the correct php.ini file does not exist on my machine.

Comment: You must look into the `.htaccess` file of your website, if another PHP configuration is entered there. Look for an entry `SetEnv PHPRC /home/www/path/yourwebsite/local_php.ini`. Alternatively you can have an entry for PHPRC in your apache configuration file under `/etc/apache2/sites-available/` . Otherwise the default /etc/php.ini will be used.

Answer (score 2):

I'd rather do this:

```
    php -i | grep ini
```

It will give you the info for ini configuration in the php console client. If you are executing apache or nginx you can see all the PHP settings with

```
    <?php
            echo phpinfo();
```